# Container Allocation | Container Size in Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, containers

As we know, Default Minimum Container Size is `1024MB`

*Consider this Scenario:*

I have setup a Hadoop Cluster <`1`-Master & `3`-Datanodes> in VIRTUAL BOX.

Namenode: master (`3GB` RAM)
Datanodes: data1 (`512MB` RAM),
`data2(512MB RAM)`,
`data3(1GB RAM)`.

Input File Size: `500MB` with Replication factor `3` (All the nodes having all the blocks)

> **QUESTION:**

**1.** Now lets say i want to run a Mapreduce Program, Will containers get allocated on data1, data2?
According to my results Job created containers on all three datanodes.

**2.** Is there any way we can specify a Job to run on specific node?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can specify a Job to run on specific node?

You shouldn't need to control this. Hadoop sends the container to the datanode where the blocks exist, so you *should be asking* how to control where blocks are placed, which I'm not sure why you'd want to do that either.

YARN has a thing called "node labels", which can allocate particular nodes to a specific scheduler queue, then you would tell the MapReduce/Tez/Spark job which queue to run within, thereby which nodes to use.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html

> lets say i want to run a Mapreduce Program, Will containers get allocated on data1, data2 ?

If blocks exist there, and you also have node managers running on the datanode with enough memory for at least one container,  then yes.

Without a NodeManager and ResourceManager, no mapreduce jobs will run

Comment: As you can see in above scenario, I have blocks on all the data nodes due to replication Factor=3.
What i intend to do is to Allocate the containers on particular datanode. eg.Datanode3

Comment: That setting doesn't guarantee all blocks equally distributed. Only one block is guaranteed to be off the first host. The other two could be placed on only one other server because I assume you left everything having the default rack placement... As explained, you cannot set a YARN container to a specific node. Nor should you. You can create a YARN queue, set a queue name for the job, and use node labels for a resource manager... That's the only way I know of. There is no other runtime configuration to give a list of servers for a YARN job